# Contiguous blocks of memory and VM

Tags: memory, memory-management, virtual

I was reading up on Virtual Memory and from what I understand is that each process has its own VM table that maps VM addresses to Physical Addresses in real memory. So if a process allocated objects continuously they can potentially be stored in completely different places in Physical Memory. My question is that if I allocate and array which is supposed to be stored in a contiguous block of memory and if the size of the array requires more space than one page can provide, from what I understand is that array will be stored contiguously in VM but possibly in completely different location in PM. Is this correct? please correct me if I misunderstood how VM works.  And if it is correct does that mean we are only concerned whether allocation is contiguous in VM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether or not something that overlaps a page boundary is actually contiguous in Physical Memory is never really knowable with modern memory handlers.  Memory glue logic essentially treats all addressable memory pages as an unordered set, and the ordering is essentially associated with a process; there's no guarantee that for different processes that end up getting assigned the same two physical memory pages (at different points in time) that the expressed relationship between those physical pages will be the same.  Effectively, there's a translation layer between the CPU and the memory that handles this stuff.

Answer (score 2):

That's right. Arrays must only looks contiguous for your application, but may be physically scattered on memory.

Comment: ... and there's no problem about it

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to add/make it clear that from a user space program's point of view, a chunk of allocated memory always *appears* contiguous. The operating system in conjunction with the CPU's Memory Management Unit (MMU) handles all virtual to physical memory mappings and the programmer *never* needs to worry about how this mapping is handled (unless, of course, said programmer is writing an operating system).

A compiler (or one who writes code in assembly) can treat a program's addresses as starting from 0 and going up until the largest address needed for that particular program. The operating system then creates a page table for each process and uses this table to partially decode a physical address for each virtual memory location. The OS treats an address in a program as two separate parts, the page address and the offset into that page. Then, the MMU translates a page address into a physical frame address. Note that a physical memory "frame" is analogous to the conceptual "page" from the standpoint of the OS; these two are of the same size (eg 4096 bytes).

Since physical memory is divided into equally sized frames, and page size is the same as frame size you can know how much of your virtual address is used as a page location and how much is an offset into that page. For instance, if your OS "allocates" 4 gigabytes to each process (as is the case in Linux), and your page/frame size is 4096 bytes, you can know that 20 bits (4,294,967,296 bytes / 4096 bytes = 2 ^ 20 = 1,048,576 pages/page addresses) of a 32 bit address are used as a page address, which will then be converted to a physical frame address by the MMU, and the remaining 12 bits are used as an offset to determine the location of the address starting from the beginning of the page/frame.

VM (user pace) address --> page + offset (OS) --> frame + offset (MMU) = physical address